# how to properly model a mesh which has had the solidify modify applied

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm failing at completing Blender Guru's donut tutorial. My issue is modelling the "icing". I cannot bend the icing mesh around the donut mesh without edges piercing through the donut mesh. I'm not even sure I'm grabbing and moving the right mesh. Is there a reason for having a duplicate mesh on the top half of the donut? Personally I thought duplicate meshes were a bad thing.

Comment: if the overlapping bother you, you can separate the icing as a new object, or delete the top part of the donut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, the top half of the donut will be selected and duplicated. (This will be converted into a separate Object). The reason why the section is duplicated is so that the icing will have the same shape as the top part of the donut (Since we added some bumps using sculpting).

Try scaling the icing a little larger than the donut and don't forget to use the snap to option along with Project Individual Element checkbox before pulling the vertices down for dribbling effect.
[image: SnapToOption]